# C# open cmd as admin via code and change font and background colors

Tags: c#

Trying to change the cmd window colors. this does not work?

```
             ProcessStartInfo p1 = new ProcessStartInfo();
             p1.Verb = "runas";
             p1.FileName = "cmd.exe";
             p1.Arguments = "color 80";
             Process.Start(p1);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "this does not work?"?

Answer (score 2):

Add `/K`:

```
ProcessStartInfo p1 = new ProcessStartInfo();
p1.Verb = "runas";
p1.FileName = "cmd.exe";
p1.Arguments = "/K color 80";
Process.Start(p1);
```

Reasoning: `COLOR` is an ["internal command"](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-internal.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for the help it works!

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/T:17"; //this would be blue colour
proc.StartInfo.Domain = "domainname"; //use if domain user
proc.StartInfo.UserName = "username";
proc.StartInfo.Password = "password";
proc.Start();
```

For the colours issue you can see here how to set:

http://ss64.com/nt/color.html